# Converting 'makefile.vc' to a '.sln' solution file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, makefile, solution

I have a **makefile.vc** which I am using to compile via this **.bat** batch file:

```bat
ECHO OFF
CLS
SET VSTools="E:\_ProgramFiles_\MS VStudio 10\VC"
CALL "E:\_ProgramFiles_\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x86 /xp /Release
CALL "E:\_ProgramFiles_\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Utilities\bin\dx_setenv.cmd"
CALL "E:\_ProgramFiles_\MS VStudio 10\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

PATH = E:\fbaxbins_v2\unixutils\bin;%path%
PATH = E:\fbaxbins_v2\perl\bin\MSWin32-x86;%path%
PATH = E:\fbaxbins_v2\nasm-2.03.01;%path%

MAKE vc
ECHO _
ECHO FB Alpha Compilation done. [MSVC Tools Environment]
ECHO _
PAUSE
```

How can I convert **makefile.vc** (which is called by `MAKE vc`) into a **.sln** solution file that I can use with Visual C++ 2010 Express with all the benefits of being able to debug, step through code and use intellisense, etc?

*(Note: `code::blocks` is fine, too, if it's easier.)*

Comment: You'd normally use the General + Makefile project template.  Fairly sure that it is not available in the Express edition.  There is otherwise no simple way to mechanically translate a makefile to a solution.

Comment: thanks for the info hans, i had a feeling it wouldnt be easy however there is a makefile project template in the express edition, im just unsure what to put in the configuration when creating the makefile, build clean rebuild preprocessor include search etc etc

Comment: You put there what you type on the command line.  Beware that make.exe is not available by default, the Microsoft version is called nmake.exe.  Does this .bat file actually work?

Comment: yeah it works and its a tutorial from here http://neosource.1emu.net/forums/index.php?topic=1476.0 if u want to recreate it also i dont type anything at the command line just double click the .bat and it does its thing

Answer (score 1):

(Answered in comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@Hans Passant wrote:

> You'd normally use the General + Makefile project template. Fairly sure that it is not available in the Express edition. There is otherwise no simple way to mechanically translate a makefile to a solution.
>
> You put there what you type on the command line. Beware that make.exe is not available by default, the Microsoft version is called nmake.exe. Does this .bat file actually work?

The OP wrote:

> it's a tutorial from here [neosource.1emu.net/forums/index.php?topic=1476.0](http://neosource.1emu.net/forums/index.php?topic=1476.0) if you want to recreate it; also I don't type anything at the command line just double click the `.bat` and it does its thing